# If a sequence of events $A_n$ converges to 0, then does the probability of the intersection equal 0?

Tags: probability

Here's an elementary question which I believe is true, but my intuition about infinite intersections is not very solid.

Let $A_n$ be a sequence of events such that $P(A_n) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Then $P(\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n) = 0$.

Suppose not, that $P(\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n) = M > 0$. This means there is a set $E$ with $P(E) = M$ such that $E \subset A_n$ for any $n$. But this means then that $P(A_n) \geq P(E) = M$, which contradicts the hypothesis.

Is this a valid argument?

Comment: Your argument is valid. You could also just to state that $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}\subseteq A_{m}$ for each $m$ and consequently
$P\left(\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}\right)\leq P\left(A_{m}\right)$
for each $m$. Then $P\left(A_{m}\right)\rightarrow0$ implies directly that $P\left(\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}\right)=0$.